# From Plotchar to line.new ? How to draw line HL2?

Tags: pine-script-v5

I would like to draw a line of hl2 when the candles make more than 40pips in 5min. For this I succeeded with plotchar but I would like to do it with one line like line.new function.

Here the script i use

```
//@version=5
indicator('Dax Patronnes ATR ', shorttitle='Patronne ATR', overlay=true, precision=6)


////////////////////// MIDDLE BOUGIE

// Input variable for maximum candlestick body size in relation to high low candlestick range.
MaxBodySize = input.float(defval=1000, title='Minimal Body Size (%)')

// If you want to draw a shape in the middle of candlestick body then this variable is needed.
// Use with plotshape and location = location.absolute
MidCandleBody = (high + low) / 2

// Create candlestick low high range comparison variable
LowHighRange = (high - low) / 100 * MaxBodySize

// Avoid negative total Candlestick body size
CandleBodySize = close >= open ? close - open : open - close

// Evaluation to determine drawing points
DrawPoint = CandleBodySize <= LowHighRange ? MidCandleBody : na

// Plot drawing points
plotchar(DrawPoint, char='.', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny)


///////////////////////////////////////////////// BOUGIE PATRONNE 5min ///////////////////////////////
open_posp = open * 1
close_posp = close * 1

// Body size as a percentage of the total candle
diffp = math.abs(close_posp - open_posp)
plot(diffp, color=color.new(color.white, 100))

open_pos2p = high * 1
close_pos2p = low * 1

// Body size as a percentage of the total candle
diff2p = (math.abs(close_posp - open_posp)) - (math.abs(close_pos2p - open_pos2p)) 


////////////// Condition bougie patronne DAX si pas avec ATR mettre s a la place de 40

isdiff2p = diffp > 40

is_five_min = (timeframe.isminutes) and (timeframe.multiplier == 5)

plotshape(is_five_min ? isdiff2p : na, style=shape.square, color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.white, text="★P★\n​")

D2 = isdiff2p ? DrawPoint : na 

// Plot drawing points
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=1)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=2)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=3)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=4)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=5)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=6)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=7)
plotchar(is_five_min ? D2 : na, char='▬', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, offset=8)
```

[image with my plotchar ---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBYG0.jpg)

Can you help me ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

and with line.new code but i but I can't get it to work like my plochar,

```
////////////////////////// LINE NEW HL2

f_delete_line_and_label(line_id) =>
    line.delete(line_id[1])

m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"5",hl2,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)

var line line_m = na

if (barstate.islast)

    line_m := line.new(bar_index[1], m, bar_index, m, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue,width=4)

    line.delete(line_m[1])
```